# Oracle XE in memory

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-xe

I have a legacy Java application using Hibernate 3 and Oracle XE (for local, prod is the full oracle DB).

I want to improve our local development speed by having a clean database/schema quickly. One way of doing this appears to be having the database in memory and resetting its data is just a matter of blowing away the instance and restarting it at some clean fixed state.

Unfortunately, there are a lot of the scripts to set up our local environment using oracle specific queries. So it is difficult just to move to another database such as h2 or even postgres.

Is there an easy way of running an oracle xe instance with in memory persistance? Such as saving the data against a tmpfs or alternatively, installing oracle xe on a VM which is restored to a snapshot each time I want a clean database?

A google about doesn't turn up any decent results for this, so here I am...

Comment: You already mentioned installing XE in a VM and restoring a snapshot each time you want a clean database - what prevents you from doing that?

Comment: If you run Enterprise Edition locally you'll have several more ways of accomplishing this.  Such as flashback tables or database, running multiple instances and switching between them, etc.  You may want to read the licenses.  Chances are you can use EE for free, for development.

Comment: Also, how long does the process take right now?  It shouldn't take more than a couple of minutes to set up even a very complicated database.  You may need to have an Oracle developer spend a few days optimizing the instllation scripts.

Comment: Takes a couple minutes to reset the database each time. Not a large amount, but instant is always better. I will look into the VM option, but that seems like a bit of a pain to keep going.

And we are using OracleXE, not EE, so I don't think the flashback feature exists.

I was really hoping there was some super fast way of doing this. I guess not.

Comment: Buy some SSD's for your developers.  Not even joking.  Probably good enough for what you are trying to achieve and cheap now too.